# patterns for synchronizing collections between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am developing a multithreaded application where multiple threads are manipulating collections of items (List type). The actions being performed include adding, removing items, looping through items and performing calculations. I am currently using locking for synchronization, but with multiple shared collections and threads it is getting a bit complex. What patterns would you suggest to effectively share data between the threads, avoid race conditions and make the code easier to maintain?

Comment: You gotta read this! http://www.albahari.com/threading/ A great resource on threading

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980283/thread-safe-collections-in-net

Answer (score 0):

Well, getting multithreaded code correct is tricky.

I would suggest looking at the Collections in [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx), they can be used without locks as long as you don't perform operations that needs transaction like behavior with multiple collections.