# enhance the performance of List<T> with locking and make it presistance?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I have a list of String like this

```
   private object = new object();
    public List<string> list {
     get{
           lock(object){
            return _list;
           }
       }
    }
    List<string> _list = new List<string>();
    //some event which trigger's 1000 in a second
    public void  event(object sender, string e){
              list.add(e);
    }
    public void processList(){
       //process the list items one by one  and remove it.      

    }
    public void writeOnDisk(){
             //write list on Disk
    }
```

now my problem is  List Processing Rate is slower than populate.
And I want to take the backup of the list on disk for application crash or system failure but afraid if write list Disk than it will slow down the
performance. I do not want to loose the data even a single item.
Can you suggest me best approach in this regard

Comment: I recommend changing your title to one which summarizes your problem. Your title could be used for tens of thousands of questions on this site.

Comment: Performance is relative. What exactly are you trying to achieve? From your description it sounds like you are trying to implement some sort of job queue? Please be a little clearer regarding "slow", "imrpove" and of course what exactly "processing" means.

Comment: If you need to persist the list, you will lose some performance while persisting it (or at least you will using your current implementation). Whether that performance loss (which can be _very_ small) is acceptable, is up to you. We can't answer this. If you may not lose a single item, you may want to consider a different approach altogether.

Comment: isnt it should be _list.add(e); ??

Comment: @Neel, no. OP created a locking wrapper for `_list`, called `list`.

Comment: @LocEngineer yes i want So called JOB Queue. 
actually job rate is 1000/sec in worst case and job completion rate is 150/sec

Comment: @CodeCaster actually i do not want to loose a single item in the list.
If i take backup after a second I think due to locking it will cause huge performance issue.

Comment: Don't think, measure.

Comment: The `lock` as written is totally useless. It is released after the `return` and before the `Add`

Comment: @xanatos what is the way write lock to make all list operation thread safe
in a single step instead of rewriting each function i.e by overriding ,overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread Safe Collections for .Net 4.0 or above.
For your case, consider using [`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265.aspx)

[Thread safe collections in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2980283/thread-safe-collections-in-net)

And one of the bottleneck should be the I/O of writing files, you may consider to write by batch instead of line by line.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Comment: @CodeCaster OP is asking the performance hit using the list, it is actually the `lock` degrades the performance. Using `ConcurrentQueue<T>` can release the expensive waiting kernel transition.

Comment: You may want to mention that in your answer. OP is also asking something like _"how to continuously persist a list?"_, so if using a different type of collection doesn't solve (much) of the problem _"items are being added faster than they are being processed"_, then this is only half an answer.

Comment: i think concurrent Collection are not efficient like list i mean queue  in some cases.

Comment: The concurrent collections are not necessarily a good choice for all scenarios, even when collections are accessed from multiple threads. In many cases a simple locking scheme can still be faster.